# How to exclude a file in war with gradle

Tags: gradle

My build.gradle includes the following (in addition to other stuff):

```
war {
    from("src/main/application") {
        into("WEB-INF/application")
    }
}
```

Along the way, it copies src/main/webapp into the root of the war file. Cool. Problem is I have one file that I’d like it to exclude from that copy. Let’s call it abc.jar. How can I make gradle continue to do everything it’s doing when creating a war file but exclude abc.jar from being copied from `src/main/webapp` to the root of the war file?

Thanks!

Blake McBride

Answer (score 5):

You can try this,

```
war {
    rootSpec.exclude("**/abc.jar")
}
```